# Change random() function for huge database

Tags: php, mysql

I need to scan database table in old web and remove dead links. For now I'm using this

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as count FROM TABLE"));
$randomrow = mt_rand(0, $row['count'] -1);
$serpq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT 1 OFFSET $randomrow") ;
if(mysql_num_rows($serpq) > 0) {
    while($keyf = mysql_fetch_array($serpq)) {
        $serpid = $keyf['id'] ;
        $url = $keyf['url'] ;
        if (!check_url($url))
            $delq=mysql_query("DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE id='$serpid'") ;
    }
}
function check_url($url) {
    $headers = @get_headers( $url);
    $headers = (is_array($headers)) ? implode( "\n ", $headers) : $headers;

    return (bool)preg_match('#^HTTP/.*\s+[(200|301|302)]+\s#i', $headers);
}
```

But this script load site in 1-2 seconds with small tables, but using this code with huge table(with 10million rows) it make web load in 5-7s. What would be efficiency way to removing dead links for huge table but make web not overloaded

Comment: Maybe you can split the query by dates? First, try the first month - after that the second month (and so on)

Comment: The slowness probably comes from the `"SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT 1 OFFSET $randomrow"` query. Doesn't `TABLE` have auto-increment ID, starting at 1 and going up to the number of rows? In that case you can do: `"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID = $randomrow"`. Because `ID` is indexed it will be a lot faster.

Comment: Yes KIKO, your suggestion will improve loading speed, but biggest problem is mt_rand function.

Comment: Since you want to remove **all** dead links - there is absolutely **no point** to check them randomly. You just start from the first and then jump to the next one. Something like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID > $previousID LIMIT 1`. And you definitely do it in a background job - not in a page in your website.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc()` .... seriously? You're still using the old-style mysql functions in PHP??? What version of PHP are you using? You do realise that those functions no longer exist in any supported version of the language? If you're worried about performance, a PHP upgrade will help you a lot, but you can't do that without updating your code to modern standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have several recomendations 1) Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead `mysql` (`mysql` was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0). 2) Decrease count of queries to database.

```
/** @var mysqli $db $row */
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($db,"SELECT count(*) as count FROM TABLE"));
$count = $row['count'];
$offset = 0;
$limit = 500;

while ($offset < $count) {
    $deleteIds = [];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset";
    if ($result = mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            if (!check_url($row['url'])) {
                // Collecting ids which we want to delete
                $deleteIds[] = $row['id'];
            }
       }
    }

    if (count($deleteIds) > 0) {
       $deleteIdsString = implode(',', $deleteIds);
       // Delete rows
       mysqli_query($db,"DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE id IN ($deleteIdsString)");
    }

    // Increase $offset
    $offset = $offset + $limit - count($deleteIds);
    // Decrease $count
    $count = $count - count($deleteIds);
}
```

Comment: mysql_* API has not been just deprecated. It has been fully **removed** from PHP 7 on.

Comment: @LelioFaieta you absolutely right! Thank you! I updated my answer

Comment: Worth pointing out that OP can't simply drop this code into his existing application as a drop+replace for his old code;it's using a different database API, so the rest of his code will also need to be updated to match as well.